# Election notifications looks slightly strange in the app

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, android-app, election

Election notifications (which appear on the site as "fredley's nomination") have an odd title in the app:

[image: What is love? Baby don't hurt me, don't hurt me, no more.]

Comment: @R.J: Based on the logo, I'd say [gaming.SE].

Comment: you can follow up on elections [here](http://elections.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Clearly it was meant 4 you.  (Looking into it)

Comment: This is the most beautiful screenshot I've ever seen.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Screenshots are [Serious Business](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta#comment88416_19775)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a bug in the public API where we weren't properly setting the title on comments on not-question-or-answer posts.  Like nominations.

This was fixed in the latest deploy of API, and should be reflected in the app now.